# Solving for real values of a quadriatic equation

Tags: integration

I have already fit a quadratic curve $ax^2 + bx + c$ to experimental data and calculated the value of its coefficients (a, b, c).

Now, I have to compute two integral functions (#14 and #17) as shown in (http://www.physics.umd.edu/hep/drew/IntegralTable.pdf).
I am using the solution equation from the table and computing its value for interval (0, +ve constant)

As the value of coefficient b is negative, I am ending up with imaginary parts in the $sqrt(4ac-b^2)$ and $tan^-1$ values.

Is there a suitable approach that I need to consider for this problem - data are from engineering measurements.

Comment: How can $b$ being negative matter? It is being squared. In any case, if #14 doesn't work then use #15 instead. #14 is when the denominator is irreducible and #15 is for when it is isn't.

Comment: Hi Bills. It is preferable that you show us your "two integral functions" here on this page, rather than sending us away from stackexchange. MathJax information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: Thanks, Using the #15 form.

Comment: Perhaps you are misdiagnosing the difficulty.  If $b^2 \geq 4 a c$, your quadratic will have real roots, so your integrand will involve division by zero if either or both roots are in $[0,a]$.  Your quadratic will have a root in the interior of $[0,a]$ if $ac < 0$ and $b > -a-c$, if $c = 0$, $a> 0$, and $-a<b<0$, or if $a>c >0$ and $-a-c < b \leq 2\sqrt{ac}$.  If this is the case for your $a,b,c$, you might like to know $\tan^{-1}(\mathrm{i} u) = \mathrm{i} \tanh^{-1}(u)$.